# Differentiable top-k function

Tags: probability, integration, functions, derivatives

Is there any differentiable function that, for a given vector, selects and encourages the top-k maximum value and suppresses the rest of the values? For example for `z = [0.01 0.1 0.04 0.5 0.24]` the top 3 would something like this:

```
top-3(z) = [1e-10 0.89 2e-9 0.98 0.92]
```

Comment: It will probably depend on how the elements of the vector are distributed as to how effective it is. Are the values in $z$ always between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin the values of z are between -1 to 1. If the values between 0 to 1 makes the case simpler that's not a big problem for me because I can normalize the elements by sigmoid function.

Comment: Should the suppressed negative values be made closer to $0$ or closer to $-\infty$? Might be worth adding any other information you have to the question.

If you use the max and min functions on the vector you could consider an approximation to the infinity norm with a very high power that might make it differentiable.

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin Thanks for your help. I only need a function that for top-k values it's very close to 1 and for the other is very close to zero. That's all I need.

Comment: Check out this paper: *A Continuous Relaxation of Beam Search for End-to-End Training of Neural Sequence Models*. Also, there is such a function in tensorflow

Comment: This paper uses a differentiable top-K operator. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.06504.pdf However, there is no analytical form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a simple differentiable top-k for PyTorch I wrote.
See also [the code here](https://gist.github.com/thomasahle/4c1e85e5842d01b007a8d10f5fed3a18).

The idea is to pick some [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), e.g. the simple $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$, and express your probabilities by $z = \sigma(x)$.
In your case that would mean
$$x = [-4.5951, -2.1972, -3.1781, -0.0000, -1.1527].$$

Now we pick a value $t\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_i \sigma(x_i + t) = k$.
In your case we would choose roughly $t=2.8301$, which would result in the "modified distribution":
$$\sigma(x+t) = [0.1462, 0.6531, 0.4139, 0.9443, 0.8426],$$
which you can check sums to 3.

**Notes**

There is a lot of flexibility in which $\sigma(x)$ function you choose, which can give you more or less "aggressive encouragement".
For example, taking $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}$ gives the output
$[0.09, 0.67, 0.34, 0.98, 0.91]$.

Another nice function is $\sigma(x) = \exp(\min(x, 0))$, which has the nice property of coinciding with the standard softmax function at $k=1$. In your case it gives $[0.07, 0.67, 0.27, 1.00, 1.00]$. Note however that it is not completely differentiable.

**Math**

The main question remains: Is this function differentiable? And if so, is it efficiently differentiable?

Let $t(x)$ be the $t$ value needed to sum to $k$ for a given set of $x$ values.
Let $f(x) = \sigma(x + t(x))$ and consider
$$
\frac{df(x)_i}{dx_j} 
= \frac{d\sigma(x_i+t(x))}{dx_j}
= \sigma'(x_i + t)\left([i=j] + \frac{dt(x)}{d x_j}\right).
$$
Issue: How do we determine $\frac{dt(x)}{d x_j}$?

Turns out this is easy using Implicit differentiation.
We simply take the derivative of the equation $k=\sum_i \sigma(x_i+t)$,
which gives us the equation
$$
\frac{dk}{d x_j}
= 0
= \sum_i \sigma'(x_i + t(x))\left([i=j] + \frac{dt(x)}{d x_j}\right)
= \sigma'(x_j+t(x)) + \frac{dt(x)}{d x_j}\sum_i \sigma'(x_i + t(x)).
$$
Solving we find
$
\frac{dt(x)}{d x_j} = \frac{-\sigma'(x_j+t(x))}{\sum_i \sigma'(x_i + t(x))}.
$
That's all there is to it.

If we define $v=\sigma'(x+t_k(x))$, the Jacobian of $\text{top}_k$ at $x$ is $J_{\text{top}_k}(x) = \text{diag}(v) - vv^T/\|v\|_1$.
Given $t$ this is easy to compute and the vector-Jacobian product $u^T J_{\text{top}_k}(x)$, needed for backpropagation, is just $u\circ v - \langle u, v\rangle v/\|v\|_1$.
This is what's implemented below and verified numerically.

To actually compute $t(x)$, I use a binary search, taking advantage of the $\sigma$ functions being monotone.
A nice property of the problem is that we only have to compute $t$ on the forward pass. When computing the gradient we simple reuse the $t$ we already computed.

**Code**

```
import torch
from functorch import vmap, grad
from torch.autograd import Function

sigmoid = torch.sigmoid
sigmoid_grad = vmap(vmap(grad(sigmoid)))

class TopK(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, xs, k):
        ts, ps = _find_ts(xs, k)
        ctx.save_for_backward(xs, ts)
        return ps

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        # Compute vjp, that is grad_output.T @ J.
        xs, ts = ctx.saved_tensors
        # Let v = sigmoid'(x + t)
        v = sigmoid_grad(xs + ts)
        s = v.sum(dim=1, keepdims=True)
        # Jacobian is -vv.T/s + diag(v)
        uv = grad_output * v
        t1 = - uv.sum(dim=1, keepdims=True) * v / s
        return t1 + uv, None

@torch.no_grad()
def _find_ts(xs, k):
    b, n = xs.shape
    assert 0 < k < n
    # Lo should be small enough that all sigmoids are in the 0 area.
    # Similarly Hi is large enough that all are in their 1 area.
    lo = -xs.max(dim=1, keepdims=True).values - 10
    hi = -xs.min(dim=1, keepdims=True).values + 10
    for _ in range(64):
        mid = (hi + lo)/2
        mask = sigmoid(xs + mid).sum(dim=1) < k
        lo[mask] = mid[mask]
        hi[~mask] = mid[~mask]
    ts = (lo + hi)/2
    return ts, sigmoid(xs + ts)

topk = TopK.apply
xs = torch.randn(2, 3)
ps = topk(xs, 2)
print(xs, ps, ps.sum(dim=1))

from torch.autograd import gradcheck
input = torch.randn(20, 10, dtype=torch.double, requires_grad=True)
for k in range(1, 10):
    print(k, gradcheck(topk, (input, k), eps=1e-6, atol=1e-4))
```